# Python enum implementation

Tags: python, enums

I have declared the enum as follows in python.I don't know how to use them.When I create an instance of this class it gives error as two arguments are required one given.

```
class CBarReference(Enum):    
ThisBar = 0,
NextBar = 1,
Undefined=2
a=CBarReference()
```

I know what error is but I don't know what to give as the second argument other than self.

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)? Or considered showing the actual code you're running and full error traceback?

Comment: Just tell how to make this type of class and the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

You should never have to create an instance of an enum; they're all accessed directly from the class, and you can just assign them to variables as you like:

```
a = CBarReference.ThisBar
b = CBarReference.NextBar
c = CBarReference.Undefined
d = CBarReference.ThisBar
assert(a == d)
assert(b != a)
assert(b != c)
```

Comment: I need to create an instance.

Comment: What do you need an instance for? The reason you're getting the error is because the constructor to Enum expects *args strings so that you can create an enum without subclassing.